# Mail is not going directly into inbox

Tags: php, email, spam, inbox

This is my code  . When i send an email from an id to its same id then email goes to junk . Unable to identify that what is the problem in this code . For example i send an email like this

From = abc@yahoo.com
 To = abc@yahoo.com 
 Then it goes directly to junk .

```
    <?php

     $name=$_POST['fName'];
     $yemail = $_POST['yEmail'];
     $femail=$_POST['fEmail'];
     $message=$_POST['message']; 
     $from=$yemail;
     $to=$femail;
     $subject="Invitation for you";
     $mailBody ="<table width='628' border='0'>

    <tr><td align='left' valign='middle'><p><br><br>Hello,<br><br>This email is a       notification to let you know that your friend has invited you to <br>visit this link <a      href=www.heed-association.org>Heed Association.</a><br><br> Your friend is using this to        help people living in Pakistan by donating some money.<br><br>So your can also contribute in the areas of Health, Education, Environment and Sustainable Development<br> in the earthquake affected areas of Kashmir to improve living conditions and alleviate community distress<br><br><hr><br><br><strong>Regards<br><br>Heed Association</p></td></tr></table>";

   $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";

    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

   $headers .= 'From:  <'.$yemail.'>' . "\r\n";


   if (mail($to, $subject, $mailBody, $headers)) {

   echo "<script language='javascript'>
            window.location = 'index.php';
            </script>";


   } else {
    echo "<script language='javascript'>
            window.location = 'tell_a_form.php';
            </script>";
    }



    ?>
```

Comment: This seems to have more to do with Yahoo's spam filters than anything in your code. It's not uncommon for spam to have the recipient's address in the From field, so this may be what Yahoo is reacting to.

Comment: it's also very common for things send with mail() to get spammed. it's NOT a good way to send mail. use a more complete system, like phpmailer or swiftmailer.

Answer (score 2):

I would say check your spam filters.  As silly as it sounds, add the email to the safe senders list.  There doesn't appear to be anything really funky going on in your code.

Comment: How can i check yahoo spam filter rules & Regulation .:)

Comment: You'll have to do that from inside the yahoo account.  It's been a while since I've used yahoo.  But typically, if you open the email while it's in the spam folder, and click the "Not Spam" button, all emails from that email should be safe.

Comment: OK i will do this process thnkz @TyrionLannister

Comment: You're welcome.  Please come back and let me know how it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably an oversensitive spam filter. A lot of programs can detect if the email wasn't actually sent from the email address listed in the "from" column. Usually the way to circumvent this is to have the email come from "no-reply@yourdomain.com".